# Do compilers assume that "this" is not nullptr in debug mode?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, this, assert

I wonder if placing `assert( this != nullptr );` on every member function is a good idea. I believe that the compiler can just decide to ignore this assert entirely, as it is *assumed* that `this` cannot be null, so the assert is always true and can be resolved at compile-time.

But if the compiler does not make this assumption, then this assert is pretty useful to catch problems early.

Do compilers assume this?

Comment: `struct foo { int bar; void baz() { bar = 1; } } * crash = 0; crash->baz();`  Hey presto, `this` is NULL.

Comment: @JonathanPotter is it? :) I say that `crash->baz()` is undefined behavior, so anything after that can happen.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Hey presto, `this` has been matter-converted into a delicious lump of cheese.

Comment: If `this` is ever null, your program is *already broken*.

Comment: @KazDragon But finding out that your program is already broken is the *raison d’être* of those asserts, isn’t it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, compilers don't typically assume that. There's even commercial code going around with these checks, some not just asserts but actually logic in them. `if (!this) { doSomeWork(); }`.

Although you couldn't reach a situation where `this` would be `NULL` without running into undefined behavior, if you're well aware of the implementation details then that's a check you can make; and yes, you're right, it *can* help in debugging.

I wouldn't put it everywhere though. Anywhere, for that matter. If `this` is indeed `NULL`, you'll likely get a crash later on when you're accessing some member. If you're not accessing any members, consider marking the method `static`. It also bloats the code unnecessarily.

Comment: Why wouldn’t you put it everywhere?

Comment: It's overkill - you'll crash on a null dereference anyway, so an assert failure does not really add anything useful.

Comment: @qdii I see little gain in it.

Comment: Thank you guys. It makes sense. I am a bit surprised with the `if (!this) doSomeWork();` though, as this is plain UB, why would you assume that your function is every going to be executed? the next version of your compiler might just ignore it.

Comment: @qdii it's low-level stuff where the behavior of the compiler is known and based upon. I agree it's not nice though.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers generally only assume anything when optimizations are turned on. So if you compile without optimizations (`assert` is enabled as long as you don't define `NDEBUG`, which is independent of optimizations), the assert will work.

It will catch problems with normal methods, but remember that for virtual methods the `this` pointer is dereferenced in order to even call the method, so the crash already happened before this check is invoked. And for most non-virtual methods the problems won't go unnoticed anyway if the method accesses any members (if it does not, it should not be an instance member function in the first place), so it's question whether adding the assert makes sense.

Comment: No this is not always dereferenced to have a call! In the case of non-virtual call, then it is not necessary to dereference the pointer.

Comment: deleting my comments, with your edit it makes no sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

To addition to what is already said, it makes not sense to test `this` for `nullptr`. Even if the pointer is indeed `nullptr`, `this` will not always be zero. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void foo() { std::cout << this << std::endl; }
    int a;
};

struct B
{
    void boo() { std::cout << this << std::endl; }
    int b;
};

struct C: public A, public B
{
};

int main()
{
    C *c = 0;
    c->foo(); // this == 0
    c->boo(); // this == 4
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it can detect errors only *sometimes*, I will still take it.

Answer (score -2):

No it is only necessary to assert it on non-virtual non-static member functions.

On static members, `this` is forbidden, so ok.

On non-virtual non-static members, as calls are statically determined by the compiler then a call like `ptr->f()` can be translated to something like `f(ptr)`, so you can have a null `this`! Strange but possible. So you can assert it.

On virtual members, as calls are dynamically computed, this can never happens. To find the function, it is necessary to dereference the pointer (consult the vtable through the pointer), so the machine will crash at that time (dereferencing a null pointer always crash), just before you can get any chance to make the effective call.

Experiment with this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
  int bar;
  void baz() { bar = 1; }
  void barf() { int i = 5; cout << "barf" << this << endl;}
  virtual void barf2() { int i = 5; cout << "barf2" <<this <<  endl;}
};
int main() {
        struct foo * crash = 0;
        crash->barf(); // do not crash
        crash->barf2(); // crash
        //crash->baz(); // crash
}
```

Comment: Because "On non-virtual non-static members, as calls are statically determined by the compiler then a call like ptr->f() can be translated to something like f(ptr), so you can have a null this!" This is incorrect. It's not valid code, it invokes undefined behavior. (Comments are superfluous when the answer to "why is this answer wrong?" lies in the other answers.)